# There are no commands defined in the "branch" namespace

Tags: symfony, symfony4, pimcore

By running this command on console in symfony/pimcore

i'm getting this error:

```
 There are no commands defined in the "branch" namespace.
```

This is the code:

```
namespace App\Command;
use Pimcore\Console\AbstractCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Pimcore\Model\DataObject;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;


/**
 * @method getContainer()
 * @property $em
 */
class Branch extends AbstractCommand
{
    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->setName('branch:import')
            ->setDescription('Branch cagai');
    }
```

and this is the command:

```
php bin/console branch:import
```

What i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

The class, should be in src path and not in bin path